# SL4 - Binding DataGridTextColumn to a property

Tags: silverlight, datagridtextcolumn

I have a DataGrid. In the DataGrid's AutoGeneratingColumn event I have some code that looks like this:

```
 if (e.Property.Name.Contains("MetaData"))
 {
                var descCol = new DataGridTextColumn(e.Property);
                var bnd = new Binding("Description");
                bnd.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                descCol.Binding = bnd;
                e.Column = descCol;
                e.Column.Header = "Description";
                return;
  }
```

The column binds to a type *MetaData* which has a string property named *Description* that I would like displayed in my DataGrid. So far I've been unable to get the value of the *Description* property to display in my DataGrid.  I think the path I am passing into the *Binding* constructor might be incorrect. I've tried "MetaData.Description" as well and it doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me properly set up the binding on my DataGridTextColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var bnd = new Binding("MetaData.Description");`

Did the trick after I also solved this issue:

[Entity Framework / RIA Services Include not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332163/entity-framwork-ria-services-include-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
var bnd = new Binding("Description");
```

to

```
var bnd = new Binding(e.Property.Name);
```

Comment: That didn't work. I think because e.Property.Name is "MetaData" where I need the Description property on the MetaData object. Any suggestions to do that?