# Binding to navigation property

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am using `Binding` on the `DataGrid` columns and have used the `Navigation Properties` in the past with expected results. I am getting the other fields to show just not these two that use `Navigation Properties`. The properties are spelled correctly as for the fields they represent. I am using `Entity Framework` for backend via `WCF`. When I check the CalenderChange object that is returning via the WCF function, I can see the `Navigation Property` and the `readonly` field is `_Firstname` and has the value I expect. I tried changing the Binding to `Binding="{Binding Personnel._Firstname}` without success.

Include it in the query:

```
db.CalenderChanges.Include("Personnel").Where({condition}).ToList()
```

XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Personnel.Firstname}"  Width="100" />
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Personnel.Lastname}"  Width="100" />
```

What am I missing? Thanks...

Comment: What is your DataGrid bound to? `IEnumerable<Personnel>` or some such? In that case you should use just `Firstname`, not `Personnel.Firstname`.

Comment: No, it is bound to the CalenderChange collection, Personnel is the navigation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WCF Ria Services, the usual reason is because using Include("Personnel") is not sufficient.

For Silverlight to get the Personnel data, you need both conditions

1. `db.CalenderChanges.Include("Personnel")` so that Personnel is returned from database
2. The metadata for Personnel navigation property is marked with `[Include]` attribute, so that Personnel is marshalled by WCF to the client. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332188/34461

sample

```
// ExtraMetadata.cs
// Add Reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll

namespace MyModel
{
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

  // This attribute tells Ria Services that the metadata
  // for the CalendarChange class is in CalenderChange.MetaData class
  [MetadataType(typeof(CalenderChange.MetaData)]
  public partial class CalenderChange {
    public class MetaData {

        // adding this attribute tells RIA services 
        // to also send this property across the wire
        [Include]
        public MetaData Personnel { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:

1. [MSDN How to add metadata classes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)
2. [MSDN IncludeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.includeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, where am I adding this, the model.Designer.vb file?

Comment: I see a SoapInclude or XmlInclude attributes, not Include??

Comment: The other thing is, I didn't have to do that for the other navigation properties on my other DataGrids...

Comment: If those entities were loaded separately then it wouldn't be necessary. You should you Fiddler to examine the response.

Comment: I just loaded Fiddler a couple of weeks ago and ran it a few times. I have no idea how to use it, but I am working on it. If you have some hints for me - I would love it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: When I debug the client I see there is no navigation properties have been serialized thru. I made a workaround by making a complex type and that gathers all the properties I need then passes a `List` of this complex type to the client, then bind on the properties and viola. I would have loved to been able to do this thru serialization, but alas no one was able to tell me how. I will keep searching and fix this when able.

Comment: I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx) may be the answer too.

Comment: No, I didn't understand how it works. I was looking for that code and did not find it - so I am now assuming I would make that class.

Comment: Yes, add the class and it should work. Also see the two references I provided in the solution.

Comment: Absolutely! I still wonder why I did not have to do this to some other Navigation Properties. Anyway it a great design to know. Thanks